# Missing Posts in Custom Taxonomy List

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

Symptom: A custom post type assigned to a taxonomy does not appear in the admin table listing all posts with a specific term attached.

From my dashboard if I click on the taxonomy under the custom post type I get a list of terms. One term was showing 3 posts but when I clicked on the number 3 the resulting list showed only 2 posts. As a test I created a new custom post and assigned it to the same term. Now the list of terms shows that this term has 4 posts attached.However, clicking on the number 4 still gives me a list of 2 posts. I moved the posts to other terms and got the same result-namely 2 posts are still missing.

I don't know where to look analyze this problem. I suspect I'm either doing something very stupid (I've checked the obvious things like the custom post being published) or perhaps something in my database is corrupted.

I don't think there is any useful code I can provide. It seems to me that the problem is associated with the posts.I have a working version of this in a development site, which works perfectly. Now I attempting to recreate the same situation on the production site and this odd symptom has appeared.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on additional information I might provide here or any likely investigations I can make to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Any chance this taxonomy belongs to more than one post type? Or belongs to a post type that is no longer in use?

Comment: @GhostToast:Thx. No. According to the set up plugin for CPT & CT its 1 on 1.

Comment: What happens when you view a query for that taxonomy term? Out in the wild. Are those posts private? Belong to a different author? Etc.

Comment: 1.Viewing Query: I did this on the website page for the taxonomy. The DEBUG-WP-Query shows a count of 3, but the page only displays 2 posts. 2.Posts are not Private. 3. All posts have the same author.

Comment: Under "Settings -> Reading" how many posts per page are allowed? Can you manually assign a greater value (or -1) in your wp_query object? `'posts_per_page' => -1`

Comment: 1. Posts Per Page 10<br />2. I switched from my own template/query to the default category template (category.php) renamed to taxonomy-tableofcontents.php when this problem arose. I don't see a way to alter the query, I'm assuming it is part of the internal code of WP. I looked in the Codex for an internal reference to where this code might exist but I couldnt find a reference.I did try switching back to my own template but that just exacerbates the problem so I'm going to avoid it for the moment.

Comment: Show us the code of the template you're using

Comment: The current template to show the list of Custom Posts in the term is the standard category.php template, unmodified. I'll show my template on pastebin when I can get it to work, but although previously working its now showing some problems so its been moved to a folder in the child folder so it can't be accessed. Although I probably have some problems with my template I found that I can detect the missing post using the dashboard so I concluded that the template was not at the heart of the primary problem.

Comment: My template can be seen at http://pastebin.com/ZexnS2j8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by deleting the taxonomy and starting a new taxonomy with a slightly different name. Initial tests show the problem has been removed, although I can't say I understand what caused it.
Before deleting the taxonomy that caused the problem I created a new test taxonomy and showed that it worked correctly. I also did a backup of the site.

Comment: Sounds like it was cursed. Bummer. At least it's working now. Sometimes namespaces fight, such as page having same slug as a post-type. Things in trash hold onto their namespaces too. Not sure what happens to dead or dying taxonomies though, since those would seem more persistent.

Comment: Nevertheless your help was much appreciated.